# Text inside of Filter chips are overflowing without wrapping to the next line

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of Filter Chips where i have my label as a text widget. I am setting the right properties on the text to wrap over to the next line but does not.

```
List<Widget>.generate(
    controller.topicListMap[topicGroup.id]!.length, (int j) {
    var subTopics = someList
    return FilterChip(
    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
    selected: false,
    label: CustomText(
    ellipsis: TextOverflow.visible,
    softWrap: true, // I am setting this to true
    maxLine: 10, // many lines
    text: subTopics[j].name,
    ),
   onSelected: (bool value) {
   setState(() {});
     },
   );
  }).toList(),
```

The problem is that from the below photo, you can see that many of the texts get wrapped to the next line but others do not. And I don't understand why

[image: Demo image]